# How do I make my footer background full screen? (HTML / CSS site)

Tags: html, css, width, footer

I've been trying to solve this for a couple of hours, but I haven't found a good solution in this forum.

So, how do I make the footer background [here](http://www.spanish-bookworld.com/) stretch all the way to the left and right, the way my header does?

I want the text to remain in four columns in the center of the screen with its current width (950px), but the background to fill the viewer's screen, whichever width that may be.

Thanks.

Maria

Comment: ewww. Why tables? All you had to do was the footer container to be 100% width, and inside it a container for your columns with 950 px width. And you set the background for the footer container:)

Comment: If only I know how to do that!

Comment: I've now figured it out. All I had to do was remove the <table> and leave the <div>. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a div outside of the main wrapper (if you have one).

This div will be a container for your footer content. Simply set it's width to 100%.

Then for the content of your footer which you want to be 950px in width, simply create another div inside the container div and assign its width to 950px and center is using margin: auto;

Example 
HTML:

```
<div id="footer-container">

  <div id="footer-content">



  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #footer-container {
  width: 100%;  
}
#footer-content{
  width: 950px;  
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple footer's table `width:100%;`

here is the screenshot after the change
[image]

by the way container design (ex. using div) are far better than tabular design....the scope of building a beautiful site using div is larger then using tables

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce what you've done here. It's exactly what I need, I just don't know where to make that change. Can you give me a clue? Thanks